# Yii2 - read log files

Tags: yii, yii2

I have made log file using Yii logger:

```
Yii::info('User is deleted');
```

But I am not able to find in the docs how can I read this file - show it on a web page. Is this possible?

Comment: You could simply use debug extension : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-debug-index.html

Comment: If you want to show those message back on website it would be better to store those messages in database. But, you still can read files using `fopen` PHP function.